# ios UITableView - functioning like a dropdown list

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu

Requirement : implementing a drowdown functionality in an UIView

The known way is using a UIWebView.

My Q is can this be done via a TableView?

Is there any way which lets me select a section(just like selecting a row), so that I can implement a hide/show cells of a section when that particular section is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if I am understanding you correctly, but it seems to me that what you want can be done like this:

1. have a UITableView with several sections;
2. each section has got just one row;
3. when a specific row for a section is selected (`didSelectRowAtIndex`), you change the data source associated to that section by adding more elements and `reloadData` on the table.
4. when a specific row for a section is selected you also modify the data source corresponding to any other section so that it only contains one row.

EDIT:

From your last comment, it seems to me that what you are trying to do is a generic dropdown menu: you click somewhere and it displays; now, in your specific case you are thinking of clicking on a table, but it could in principle be anywhere else. I am saying this (if I am not wrong), because if it is so, then you can find ready-made implementations, like [WEPopover](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover), and you could save some effort.

Going back to your asking, in the case you are mentioning, you can animate the height of the table view `frame` (or `bounds`), so that its content is displayed little by little, as the view height increases; have a look at this [Tutorial about Core Animations](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial-intro-core-animation).

Comment: Yesss. Nice. This is what I was looking for, certainly better than what I was thinkin. Just 1 point, is there any way we could animate that? So that it feels like a dropdown list. I was thinking of detecting which row is clicked, and depending on that generating 1 more tableView from that row's position, for which I would have added some animation.